# flutter give me exception on try catch

Tags: json, flutter, exception, try-catch, delete-file

```dart
try {
        jsonFile.delete();
        fileExists = false;
        print("File deleted");
      } catch(e){
        print("File does not exists!");
      }
```

I want to handle the exception in case the file doesn't exist but it give me this exception:
**Unhandled Exception: FileSystemException: Cannot delete file, path = '*file path*' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)**
instead of handling it and send me a message in the console, it's normale?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`jsonFile.delete()`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.13.4/dart-io/FileSystemEntity/delete.html) returns a Future, meaning it will run asynchronously and therefor not send errors to your catch block, which runs synchronously. You can await the result:

```
try {
    await jsonFile.delete();
    fileExists = false;
    print("File deleted");
} catch(e){
    print("File does not exists!");
}
```

Or, if you want to keep it asynchronous, you can use `.catchError()` on the Future to catch errors:

```
try {
    jsonFile.delete()
      .then((value) => print("File deleted"));
      .catchError((error) => print("File does not exist"));
    fileExists = false;
} catch(e){
    print("File does not exists!");
}
```

For more about Futures and working with them, see [this page](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Future-class.html).